# netbeans not found Qt Designer

Tags: windows, qt, netbeans-7, qt-designer

When i want to open a **.ui** file in **netbeans**, its alert that: **`Failed to start Qt Designer. Make sure it is installed and added to PATH`**

I use win vista and opensource **Qt 4.8.4** and **Qt creator 2.6.1**  in Addr. `C:\Qt\qtcreator-2.6.1\bin\qtcreator.exe`
and i have **Qt designer** in Addr. `C:\Qt\4.8.4o\bin\designer.exe`
my netbeans build tools options qmake set on `C:\Qt\4.8.4o\bin\qmake.exe`

thanx

Comment: Have you added it to `PATH` like it asked?

Comment: no, where is the `PATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PATH` is a Windows environment variable.  It is a list of paths that the OS uses to look for executables and libraries.

You need to add the path to Qt Designer to that list.  Right-click on 'My Computer', hit 'Properties', go to 'Advanced system settings', and click on the 'Environment Variables' button.  Find 'Path' (or 'PATH') in the System Variables group, and click edit.  The paths are delimited by a semi-colon, add the Qt Designer path to the end.

Comment: thanks! I add `bin` directory to path and restart netbeans. now when i open a .ui file in netbeans its opening in Qt Designer!